# should_receive also stubs the method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to test a flow:

`MyClass.should_receive(:my_method)` 
when I use the above code, `my_method` returns nil and 
when I don't it enters the method and does what it does.

I don't want to stub the method, just test that it's passing there.

Any Ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#delegating-to-the-original-implementation):

> When working with a partial mock object, you may occasionally want to
>   set a message expecation without interfering with how the object
>   responds to the message. You can use `and_call_original` to achieve
>   this

So you can add to your code:

```
MyClass.should_receive(:my_method).and_call_original
```

In the new expect syntax, this would be:

```
expect(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).and_call_original
```